# Emphasis level map with ffmpeg using NVENC

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, roi, nvenc

I am trying to have different compression levels, to different regions in the video.
ffmpeg has something called "addroi", but it's just a recommendation and doesn't guarantee the absolute level of compression.
Nvidia NVENC has something called Emphasis Level Map, I am hoping this will be able to achieve an accurate level of compression per region.

I am unable to find how to do this via ffmpeg executable, so I am starting to try to do this using the ffmpeg SDK.
Do you have any idea how to do this via the ffmpeg.exe, instead of using the SDK?

Here is what I am talking about in the NVIDIA documentation:

https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/nvenc-video-encoder-api-prog-guide/index.html#emphasis-map

Comment: I try to use addroi but it seems even not working, does it work for you? The command I used is ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c:v h264_nvenc -qp 50 -vf addroi=0:0:iw/2:ih:-1 -y out.mp4

Comment: This is the command I have been using(notice the qoutes around addroi) %commandPath% -y -i %aviPath% -crf %targetCRF% -vf "addroi=0:%atlasHeight%:iw:%LLHeight%:-1" -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p %targetPath%/%targetName%.mp4 Notice that -1 can only work on CRF that is 1 or greater, on 0 it won't have any affect.

Comment: It's also possible nvenc doesn't support addroi the same way libx264 does

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems the nvenc doesn't support addroi and I can't use -qp to determine the quality, only -crf and -b:v works.